# String issue - Java

Tags: java, string, compare, equals, equality

I am writing a program for class in which I analyze different product codes entered. It is pretty simple but I am having a problem. I am trying to end a loop if a user enters an "E" or "e". However, it does not end the loop at all. This is at the end of a while statement so setting loop to false should end it and it doesn't even output the totals either so I have messed something up. Code is a string type.

```
        // Prompt the user for another company code or exit
        System.out.print("Enter the company code or type 'e' to exit: ");

        // Input the user's company code
        code = scan.nextLine();

        // Check to see if the user wants to exit
        if (code == "e" || code == "E") {
            // Output final statistics
            System.out.print("Total valid codes: " + valid + "/n");
            System.out.print("Total banned codes: " + banned);

            // End the loop     
            loop = false;
        }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I can't see any loop in code?

Comment: can you put in the loop code?  I'm thinking you want to use "break;" instead to end the loop, but I don't know what your loop looks like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `code.equals("e") || code.equals("E")` (or just `code.equalsIgnoreCase("e")`). This is because `==` does *identity* comparison ("are *x* and *y* the same object?"), whereas `equals` does *value* comparison ("do *x* and *y* have the same value?").

Comment: Thank you so much to you and everyone who answered.

Comment: as a followup question, I take TRV2475A5R-14 and create a character array for just 2475. I need to make sure it contains only numeric characters. How do you recommend I do this?

Comment: @Brooks: You should ask a new question on the site for that. However, here's a one-line answer: `code.matches("\\d+")`.

Answer (score 4):

When comparing `Strings` you should *always* use the `equals` method rather than `==`, so

```
if ("e".equals(code) || "E".equals(code))
```

is probably what you want.

The reason for this is that `Strings` are special objects in Java. They are immutable, and they can be *interned* to optimize memory usage. Constants (like the "e" and "E" in your code) are automatically interned by the compiler, but the `scanLine` method will probably return a non-interned String so the `==` comparison will fail.

Remember, when we're talking about objects, `==` checks for *reference equality* not *value equality*, i.e. `a == b` means "do `a` and `b` refer to the same object?". It's possible for `a.equals(b)` to be true but `a == b` to be false.

Comment: +1 for talking about interning; I am currently writing some slides and one of the topics I talk about is how immutable objects with equal value can be coalesced and/or interned. :-D

Answer (score 2):

Use **equalsIgnoreCase()**

Your code will be

```
if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
            // Output final statistics
            System.out.print("Total valid codes: " + valid + "/n");
            System.out.print("Total banned codes: " + banned);

            // End the loop     
            loop = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare strings using `.equals()` not `==`

Answer (score 1):

Strings are compared via `equals` not `==`

```
if (code.equals("e") || code.equals("E")) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.equals` when comparing strings.

In your case you can even use

```
if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
```

The reason is that `==` checks whether two objects are the same object. You can have two different string objects represent the same string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.equalsIgnoreCase("e")`, == compares the addresses of the Objects in memory and `.equals(String)` is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

** LOOP *** {

```
    // Prompt the user for another company code or exit
    System.out.print("Enter the company code or type 'e' to exit: ");

    // Input the user's company code
    code = scan.nextLine();

    // Check to see if the user wants to exit
    if (code.equals("e") || code.equals("E")) {  // <====== see new code
        // Output final statistics
        System.out.print("Total valid codes: " + valid + "/n");
        System.out.print("Total banned codes: " + banned);

        // End the loop     
        //loop = false;
        break;  // <====== see new code
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would say for things like codes its better to use Java enums. With enums you can use == operator for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use

```
code.equalsIgnoreCase("e")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the explanation given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/1394464

```
== tests for reference equality.

.equals() tests for value equality.
```

Therefore, if you actually want to test whether two strings have the same value you should use .equals() instead of ==.

So

```
if(code == "e" || code == "E")
```

should become

```
if(code.equals("e") || code.equals("E"))
```